# Which simple webservice for low bandwidth?

Tags: java, android, sockets, soap, proxy

My goal is the following, and I do not know which direction I should ho to.

- a webapp
- a client that can interact with the webapp not by browser, but by "something other".

This connection might be established by: RMI, Rest, Soap, Socket, etc (which I have hardly any experience in).
The client should be able to trigger methods/processes on the server. The client should also get values back (boolean, integer, string) and handle them specifically.
It should moreover works with lower/wifi bandwith android, and not have any special requirements like opening extra ports on firewall or so.
Which approach might fit my needs best? Which technology should I go deeper into? 
Is Rest the way to go?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Do you want best performance?

Comment: not necessarily, but performance should not be bad either

Comment: Sounds cool. But fully native web apps without using a browser are going to be hard. After android 3.0, All of your network operations have to be put on a background thread. Could be a nightmare everytime a user interacts with the app.